# Android Crashlytics wrong line number

Tags: android, crashlytics

I've added Crashlytics to my project according to documentation and when I make NPE crash for testing it works ok in debug build where I have code:

```
108    User u = null;
109    u.callMethod();
```

The crash is uploaded and it's pointing the line **109**.

However when I use `Export Crashlytics-enabled Android Application` the crash line gets uploaded and is **108**.

What could cause this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable` to your `proguard-project.txt` or other proguard config file?

Comment: Sorry, didn't help to me.